# How to programmatically dismiss a UISearchBar?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

I have a standard table view, with a UISearchController implemented via a NIB. I want to mimic what happens when the user clicks "Cancel" in the search bar - the normal behaviour is that the search bar goes away and the table returns to its original state. Basically, I want to have the same happen when the user selects an item that appears in their search results.

I can't find *anywhere* the process of what happens when the user clicks "Cancel".

Answer (score 131):

This is a sorta old question, but I just beat my head against this for an hour or two and finally figured it out, so I thought I'd share for posterity. At first I tried doing things like resigning first responder / deleting search text / etc by hand, but in this view I wanted the user to be able to possibly use the search bar multiple times, and doing things manually was meaning that the search bar would have had to be re-set-up every time the user started editing it again - seemed like the wrong approach. Here's what I did:

I had already added the search bar, with the optional search display controller, in Interface Builder.  In my implementation, I set up a UISearchDisplayController IBOutlet, and then linked it to the search display controller using IB.  Finally, in the spot where I want to dismiss the search bar, I simply have to call:

```
[mySearchController setActive:NO];
```

Works like a charm!

Comment: Thank you! This problem went away for me in the app I was working on, but great to know for next time.

Comment: There's also a setActive:animated: variant, which was more suitable for my case. Thanks!

Comment: This seems to only clear the search text and hide the current results, but keeps the search field focused and in search mode, at least under iOS 7.

Comment: I couldn't just add a iboutlet that easily. I had to add it and synthesize it for it to work.

Answer (score 5):

Usually, the searchBarCancelButtonClicked: method looks something like this:

```
yourSearchBar.text = @"";
[yourTableView reloadData];
[yourSearchBar resignFirstResponder];
```

Comment: If I do those three things, the result is that the keyboard is dismissed and the search results table goes, but the main table behind remains dimmed and the search field is still visible. Clicking in the dimmed table completes the steps that I want to happen: the search bar goes and the main table is made visible.

Comment: There is no search results table; it's the same table which has had some of its cells removed because of the search, unless you're using a UISearchDisplayController.

Comment: Sorry, I just meant the different states of the table. From my original question: "I want to mimic what happens when the user clicks "Cancel" in the search bar - the normal behaviour is that the search bar goes away and the table returns to its original state. Basically, I want to have the same happen when the user selects an item that appears in their search results.

Comment: Does selecting a cell load a detail view? If so, you probably don't want to do [yourTableView reloadData]; because when they return, they would expect the results of their search to still be there. Drilling down into a detail view also removes the keyboard automatically. If this is not the case, then just implement my answer in didSelectRowAtIndexPath:, probably without the [yourTableView reloadData];

Comment: Yes Yes Yes!! It's saved my time! Thanks man for this solution!

Answer (score 5):

Here is how i solved this problem after a few hours of experiments =)

```
for(UIView *subView in self.searchDisplayController.searchBar.subviews){
    if([subView isKindOfClass:UIButton.class])
    {
        UIButton *cancelButton = (UIButton*)subView;
        [cancelButton sendActionsForControlEvents: UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        break;
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Set active also cleared my `UISearchBar` text and so my array of data items would get cleared, therefore this worked for me:

```
self.searchController.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
```

This cleared the `UIDimmingView` and left my search text alone - perfect in my case.